# Error after migration from django 1..x and cms-plugins to djangocms plugins and django 2

Tags: django, python-3.5

When upgrading the old packages in the file requirements.txt of my application, of which the deprecated cms-plugins to the newer djangocms-plugins, I got the following error:

```
<code>

(tonhausPZ) root@manelmr-Lenovo-G560:/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ# python manage.py migrate  djangocms-picture
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(tonhausPZ) root@manelmr-Lenovo-G560:/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ# python src/manage.py migrate  djangocms-picture
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djangocms_picture/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cms.models import CMSPlugin
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pagemodel import *  # nopyflakes
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 24, in <module>
    from cms.models.managers import PageManager, PageNodeManager
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/models/managers.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cms.utils.i18n import get_fallback_languages
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/utils/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cms.utils.conf import get_site_id  # nopyflakes
  File "/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ/src/tonhaus/tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/utils/conf.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cms import __version__
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__'
(tonhausPZ) root@manelmr-Lenovo-G560:/home/manel-mr/PhilippZ# 
</code>
```

I couldn't find a solution to this error.

The updated requirements.txt file is:

```
<code>
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
cmsplugin-filer==1.1.3
Django==2.2.8
django-appconf==1.0.3
django-classy-tags==0.9.0
django-cms==3.7.1
django-compressor==2.3
django-filer==1.6.0
django-formtools==2.2
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-libsass==0.7
django-mptt==0.10.0
django-polymorphic==2.0.3
django-rosetta==0.9.3
django-sekizai==1.0.0
django-select2==7.1.2
django-social-share==1.3.2
django-treebeard==4.3
django-uuidfield==0.5.0
djangocms-admin-style==1.4.0
djangocms-attributes-field==1.1.0
djangocms-link==2.5.0
djangocms-rosetta==0.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor==3.8.0
easy-thumbnails==2.6
gevent==1.4.0
greenlet==0.4.15
gunicorn==20.0.4
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
libsass==0.19.4
microsofttranslator==0.8
olefile==0.46
Pillow==6.2.1
polib==1.1.0
pytz==2019.3
rcssmin==1.0.6
requests==2.22.0
rjsmin==1.1.0
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
Unidecode==1.0.23
urllib3==1.25.7
webencodings==0.5.1
</code>
```

The file settings.py includes the following code:

```
<code>
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
SITE_ID = 1

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': (
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
                'cms_tonhaus.context_processors.product_ordering',
                'cms_tonhaus.context_processors.wishlist_count',
            ),
        'loaders': (
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
            )
        }
    },
]

MIDDLEWARE = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'filer',
    'cms',
    'django_select2',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_audio',
     'djangocms_video',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'compressor',
    'django_social_share',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_rosetta',
    'rosetta',
    'cms_tonhaus',
    'tonhaus'
)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

LANGUAGES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('de', gettext('de')),
    ('it', gettext('it')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)

</code>
```

The database tables are :

```
<code>
mysql> use www_tonhaus
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_www_tonhaus               |
+-------------------------------------+
| auth_group                          |
| auth_group_permissions              |
| auth_permission                     |
| auth_user                           |
| auth_user_groups                    |
| auth_user_user_permissions          |
| cms_aliaspluginmodel                |
| cms_cmsplugin                       |
| cms_globalpagepermission            |
| cms_globalpagepermission_sites      |
| cms_page                            |
| cms_page_placeholders               |
| cms_pagepermission                  |
| cms_pageuser                        |
| cms_pageusergroup                   |
| cms_placeholder                     |
| cms_placeholderreference            |
| cms_staticplaceholder               |
| cms_title                           |
| cms_tonhaus_artistmodel             |
| cms_tonhaus_categorymodel           |
| cms_tonhaus_productmodel            |
| cms_tonhaus_simplefilerimagemodel   |
| cms_tonhaus_wishlistmodel           |
| cms_tonhaus_wishlistmodel_products  |
| cms_treenode                        |
| cms_urlconfrevision                 |
| cms_usersettings                    |
| cmsplugin_filer_image_filerimage    |
| django_admin_log                    |
| django_content_type                 |
| django_migrations                   |
| django_session                      |
| django_site                         |
| djangocms_audio_audiofile           |
| djangocms_audio_audiofolder         |
| djangocms_audio_audioplayer         |
| djangocms_audio_audiotrack          |
| djangocms_file_file                 |
| djangocms_file_folder               |
| djangocms_googlemap_googlemap       |
| djangocms_googlemap_googlemapmarker |
| djangocms_googlemap_googlemaproute  |
| djangocms_link_link                 |
| djangocms_picture_picture           |
| djangocms_snippet_snippet           |
| djangocms_snippet_snippetptr        |
| djangocms_style_style               |
| djangocms_text_ckeditor_text        |
| djangocms_video_videoplayer         |
| djangocms_video_videosource         |
| djangocms_video_videotrack          |
| easy_thumbnails_source              |
| easy_thumbnails_thumbnail           |
| easy_thumbnails_thumbnaildimensions |
| filer_clipboard                     |
| filer_clipboarditem                 |
| filer_file                          |
| filer_folder                        |
| filer_folderpermission              |
| filer_image                         |
| filer_thumbnailoption               |
| menus_cachekey                      |
| reversion_revision                  |
| reversion_version                   |
+-------------------------------------+

</code
```

I am using python 3.5 and the newest versions of packages of which django 2.x , knowing that the old version of the application uses python 2.7, django 1.x  and cmsplugins.

Comment: Ideas:
1. Can you go to that directory in your venv called cms? Just want to know if there is a file named `__version__.py` there since you have an import error.
2. Maybe you're in the wrong directory? (Just reading that first bit. Don't think you should've done src/manage.py) Go back a dir with `cd ..` then try again with `python manage.py migrate djangocms-picture`.

Comment: There is no a file named __version__.py in the folder tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/ in my venv called tonhausPZ. I found two different files __version__.py in the folders tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/updatable, tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests, tonhausPZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests. Always getting the same error with python manage.py migrate...knowing that I did not get this error in the former migrations. I don't know which change happened to my code to generate this error whenever I type a command

Comment: Let's see if I can walk through the problem with you. First, I checked https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/utils/conf.py because that was the source of your problem. Did you uninstall the django-cms package? If not, go to cms/__init__.py.

When you get there, check that it matches with this file: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/__init__.py

If you don't have Django-cms installed, that's your problem.